# How can I set a validationmessage for inputfield binded to entitymodel?

Tags: c#, validation, razor-pages

How can i set a validation message on all of these fields? Im not sure how to set it when I bind everything directly to my entitymodel Cancellation? I tried setting a validationmessage directly in my entityclass nut no luck.

This is my razorpage

```
@page
@model Index
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<div class="body-content">
    <form id="avboka-form" method="post">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-med-5">
                <label asp-for="Cancellation.Elev"></label>
                <input type="text" id="elev" asp-for="Cancellation.Elev" class="form-control">
                <span asp-validation-for="Cancellation.Elev"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-med-5">
                <label asp-for="Cancellation.Dag"></label>
                <input asp-for="Cancellation.Dag" type="datetime" id="datepicker" class="datepicker1 form-control">
                <span asp-validation-for="Cancellation.Dag"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.SelectedKommun, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-med-2" })
            <div class="col-med-5">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Cancellation.KommunId, new SelectList(Model.Kommun, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "kommun" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedKommun, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.SelectedFordon, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-med-2" })
            <div class="col-med-5">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Cancellation.FordonId, new SelectList(Model.Fordon, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "fordon" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedFordon, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-med-5">
            <label asp-for="Cancellation.Skola.Namn"></label>
            <select id="skola" name="Cancellation.SkolaId" class="form-control">
                @foreach (var schools in Model.School)
                {
                    <option value="@schools.Id">@schools.Namn</option>
                }
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="Cancellation.SkolaId"></span>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="save" value="Avboka skolskjuts" class="vt-btn" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is part of my pagemodel where i bind my input-fields. The selects is collected from other tables and therefore is never empty.

```
[BindProperty]
public Avbokning Cancellation { get; set; }

public Index(SqlAvbokningData<Avbokning> avbokningRepo, SqlKommunData<Kommun> kommunRepo, SqlFordonData<Fordon> fordonRepo, SqlSkolaData<Skola> skolaRepo)
{
    _avbokningRepo = avbokningRepo;
    _kommunRepo = kommunRepo;
    _fordonRepo = fordonRepo;
    _skolaRepo = skolaRepo;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
{

    Kommun = await _kommunRepo.GetKommuner();
    Fordon = _fordonRepo.GetFordon();
    Municipalities = await _kommunRepo.GetAll();
    Vehicle = await _fordonRepo.GetAll();
    School = await _skolaRepo.GetAll();
    return Page();
}


[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //if (!Cancellation.Validate())
        //    return Redirect("/");
        await _avbokningRepo.Add(Cancellation);
        return Redirect("/Tack");
    }
    return RedirectToAction("OnGet");

}
```

Comment: which fields are you trying to validate

Comment: also do not use your entitymodels in the views but rather create viewModels and pass them to your views. In the viewModel classes set your validation messages (Required etc). When loading the view gather your data and map it to your viewModels and pass it to the view i.e. return View(viewModel). When submit the view, validate the viewModel and map it back to your entities or do what ever needs to be done

Comment: You can use DataAnnotation attributes on the properties of your entity, but the recommended approach is to apply them to PageModel properties or to the properties of an Input/ViewModel (https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/validation). Also, you should consider using Tag Helpers instead of Html helpers in ASP.NET Core (https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/).

Answer (score 0):

Validation in MVC can be done with a viewmodel. You specify your model this way:

```
 public class LogOnViewModel
 {
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "RequiredField")]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "RequiredField")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
  }
```

Once you get to the web page itself, the ValidationMessageFor will then validate the fields based on the data annotations you have placed on your viewmodel, as you pass that on to the web page.

In the controller you can pass it on to the page by means like this:

```
var viewModel = new LogOnViewModel();
// do stuff
return View(viewModel);
```

It's not a perfect example, but this should give some idea of how you can use it.